# ASP .NET Entity: EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm getting this error when i run my server:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>        Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Here's my ActionResult where this exception occurs, at line in foreach loop.  Table bid from database has foreign key constraint to AspNetUser table.

```
public ActionResult Details(long? id)
{
if (id == null)
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

auction auction = db.auctions.Find(id);

if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
    ViewBag.UserRole = "Administrator";
else if (User.IsInRole("User"))
    ViewBag.UserRole = "User";
else
    ViewBag.UserRole = "Guest";

var bids = from b in db.bids
            where b.IDAuc == id
            orderby b.tokens
            descending select b;

var bidsLimited = bids.Take(10);
var users = from b in db.AspNetUsers
            select b;

int count = bidsLimited.Count();
long[] prices = new long[count];
string[] bidders = new string[count];
string[] times = new string[count];
string[] states = new string[count];
int i = 0;

foreach (var bid in bidsLimited)
{
    prices[i] = bid.tokens;
    bidders[i] = bid.AspNetUser.Email; // HERE IS EXCEPTION
    times[i] = bid.created.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");
    states[i++] = "Open";
}

if (auction.state == "Sold")
    states[0] = "Sold";

ViewBag.count = count;
ViewBag.prices = prices;
ViewBag.bidders = bidders;
ViewBag.times = times;
ViewBag.states = states;
ViewBag.IDAuction = id;

return View(auction);
}
```

**Here's detailed error:** [image]

I'm really confused, first time seeing this exception, hope someone will help me solve this out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `var users = from b in db.AspNetUsers select b;`  Try eager loading the user info in your `var bids` query instead. i.e.  something like `from b in db.bids.Include('AspNetUser')`

Comment: Didn't mention what's weird, that I've already finished coding one application with exactly the same code, and now on this other I'm getting exception on previous same one, there's no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible one of the records in the `bid` variable doesn't have an AspNetUser ID value specified, so the relationship is null?  Another workaround is I do sometimes have strange errors like this, where even though the ID is specified, the error still persists.  Since you've loaded up all of the related user data into the users variable, you could change the line from:

```
bidders[i] = bid.AspNetUser.Email; // HERE IS EXCEPTION
```

To

```
bidders[i] = users.First(i => i.AspNetUserID == bid.AspNetUserID).Email;
```

i.AspNetUserID is the AspNetUser's ID field (I don't know what it's called, so replace i.AspNetUserID with the correct value) to the bid table's AspNetUserID field (again, replace with the correct name).

If that fails, the user found is NULL, there is a problem somewhere that needs to be determined; the user isn't linked and coming back, and for that you need to identify the specific record in the bid variable that isn't linked properly...

Comment: I've just tried it, and I'm getting same exception error. By the way, it's impossible to have null reference to AspNetUser table, because AspNetUser is creating Bid object, and putting itself to the Id field.

Comment: How is AspNetUser creating Bid object?  In a stored proc or trigger?

Comment: On client side by button click, logged user is creating bid, so procedure.